What's the tax system for foreign money earned in India through an international gaming business?
I run a solo gaming international business from India. People purchase gaming virtual products in GBP (Pounds) through my website hosted on "Tebex" which charges Sales Tax, Gateway Fee & Platform Fee for providing me the Website. After the taxes, the remaining money is converted to USD and sent to my Indian PayPal Business Account. Within a day or two, PayPal converts the USD amount into INR and transfers it to my bank account. What's the tax system for that?
